# AWS EMR Steps and HDFS Merge; Scala Shell Commands`

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, merge, hdfs, emr

I'm using AWS EMR for running some of our spark programs. 
The data lake is built on S3 and has raw and curated layers. the Spark program draws the data from Raw zone and does some transformations to put into the curated layer. I first store the results locally on HDFS and then do a distcp to S3;

All along, we were using SSH to log in to EMR and deploy the jar and run; In production, however, our customer has said no to using SSH. We made changes to our program to make it run as steps using below command

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-CXXXXXXXXXJ --steps Type=Spark,Name="RUN MJ",ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,Args=[--class,sparkMultiJoins.GenomeSparkJoins,s3://marketing-analytics-platform/genome_install/libs/SparkFrameWork-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar,dbo.Property,abc,genomedb,genomedb];
```

I'm successfully able to run the program; But while executing shell commands to do the HDFS merge from the scala I have run into problems; The below is the code for merge.

```
     val MergeFiles = "hadoop fs -text " +  HDFSOutPath + "/part* | hadoop fs -put - " + HDFSOutPath +"/"+fileName+".csv"
      //////execute the dynamically constructed command
 MergeFiles.!
```

sample output after param substitution looks like below

```
hadoop fs -cat hdfs://ip-10-11-111-111.xxx.com:8020/StageData/Property/* | hadoop fs -put - hdfs://ip-10-11-111-111.pnmac.com:8020/StageData/Property/Property.csv
```

While the above executes, it throws the output of the cat command- i.e all the data on the files- on to std out-- i.e it can be seen on the stdout in the aws log. For this reason the job executes for ever; I was expecting it to behave the way it would if i executed the hadoop fs (command above) on the emr cluster;

Please note that I have tried using coalesce(1) method for merge and dropped it as it was mighty slow.

Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: why dont you try using the api instead of hdfs commands?

Comment: Can you please let me know the specifics?